# How to make the image stay inside the container without being overflowed

Tags: angular, html, css

The image inside the container is being overflowed even after giving `overflow:hidden` to the container .

This doesn't happen at all and this shouldn't happen after giving `overflow:hidden`, But it still bugs out for some reason

Any help would be appreciated.

Image

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6" *ngFor="let images of brandImages">
      <div class="brands">
        <img src="{{ images }}" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.brands {
  margin-top: 18px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to recreated your problem: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4k0kynkv3)
Everything seems to work as intended, so i think it might be browser related. Does this problem occurs on every browser? Have you scaled your page (zoom)?

Comment: I think its the browser issue then, Cuz when I zoom out from the browser, that's when the issue happens. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```css
.brands 
{
...
clip-path: rectangle(0, 0, 100%, 200px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `img` `max-width:100%;` and `height:auto;` or if you're using `bootstrap` give it a class of `img-responsive` or `img-fluid` depending on your version.